# How to convert the following HOC implementation into a react hook implementation

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

**I need convert the following HOC implemenation of react redux into a react hook implementation**
I am a beginner in react hook, i find it fascination and i need to replace connect() function and map dispatch to props into dispatch and userSelector

```
    import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
    import { connect } from 'react-redux'
    import { fetchUsers } from '../actions/user.action'

    function UsersContainer ({ userData, fetchUsers }) {
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchUsers()
    }, [])
    return userData.loading ? (
        <h2>Loading</h2>
    ) : userData.error ? (
        <h2>{userData.error}</h2>
    ) : (
        <div>
        <h2>Users List</h2>
        <div>
            {userData &&
            userData.users &&
            userData.users.map(user => <p>{user.name}</p>)}
        </div>
        </div>
    )
    }

    const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        userData: state.user
    }
    }

    const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        fetchUsers: () => dispatch(fetchUsers())
    }
    }

    export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
    )(UsersContainer)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import `useSelector` and `useDispatch` hooks from **react-redux**.
and use them like so:

```
// useSelector hook allows you to extract data from the Redux store state
const userData = useSelector(state => state.user);

// useDispatch hook returns a reference to the dispatch function from the Redux store.  
// You may use it to dispatch actions as needed.
const dispatch = useDispatch();
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(fetchUsers());
}, []);
```